# Linux - Passing parameters correctly to be used by a C program

Tags: c, linux, assembly

Below is a 32 bit function that I am writing to be used by a C program in Linux. This code passes two parameters (a and b). I am trying to ensure I setup the stack frame correctly such that the parameters (a and b) print correctly and the function returns zero. During testing I the a parameter is not always printing correctly what is being passed from the C program. Please let me know if you see anything I am missing.

```
bits 32

global galoisMultiply

extern  printf                       ; the C function, to be called

segment .bss                         ; for uninitialized data
section .data                        ; for initialized data
str1:   db "a value = %d", 10, 0
str2:   db "b value = %d", 10, 0

section .text                        ; for code
; Galois Field (256) Multiplication
; int galoisMultiply( int a, int  b);

galoisMultiply:    
  push ebp                   ; 2 lines are equivalent to enter
  mov ebp, esp
  sub esp, 32                ; allocate 32 bytes of local stack space
  push eax
  push ebx
  push ecx
  mov ecx, dword[ebp + 8]
  push ecx
  push  dword str1          ; string to be printed
  call printf              ; printf
  add esp, 8               ; cleanup 
  mov ecx, dword[ebp + 12]
  push ecx
  push  dword str2          ; string to be printed
  call printf              ; printf
  add esp, 8               ; cleanup 
Done:
  pop ecx
  pop ebx
  pop eax
  add esp, 32             ; deallocate 32 byte of local variable space 
  mov eax, 0              ; put the return value of p in eax
  mov esp, ebp            ; 2 lines are equivalent to leave
  pop ebp
  ret
```

Comment: Call it just a curiosity, but what does  `galoisMultiply` do that is so special you can't do it in C and that you have to call `printf` via assembly for?

Comment: What exactly do you see?  `not always printing correctly` isn't very specific.  I didn't see anything wrong with your code, other than being hard to read because of an excess of blank lines even within a block of related instructions.  Also a huge waste of instructions and no actual multiply... You might want to look at the code for `par2` to see how 8-bit Galois-Field multiplies can be implemented.  Or better, look at something that uses `pshufb` to do it with a parallel LUT in an xmm register.

Comment: push/pop to save/restore registers have to be used in LIFO order.  That would be a problem if you needed to save/restore ecx and eax, but you don't.  It's ok to clobber the caller's eax, ecx, and edx; See the calling convention docs in [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: Your whole function should just be `push [esp+8]` / `push [esp+8]` / `push fmt_a_and_b` / `call printf` / `add esp, 12` / `ret`.   Use a multi-line format string that prints both in one call to printf.

Comment: More importantly, don't use debug-prints in asm.  Use a debugger instead to look at registers and memory as you single-step.  (See the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)